# plotting fitted linear graphs at two different horizontal range values

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting two graphs using gnuplot. First plot is actual data and the second one is the fitting of the data.

The script I used for plotting this is shown here below:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset 


set terminal png enhanced
set terminal pngcairo enhanced color dashed
set output 'msd-maltoLyo12per-225ns.png'

##########################################
set macros

labelSIZE="font 'Arial,24'"
ticFONT="font 'Arial,16"
set key font 'Arial,14'
set key spacing 1.5 samplen 5 
##########################################

set xrange [0:225]  
set yrange [0:11000]


set xtic @ticFONT
set ytic @ticFONT
set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror
##############################

set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "red"  lw 2.0 
set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "blue"     lw 2.0 
set style line 3 lt 3 lc rgb "coral"    lw 2.0 
set style line 4 lt 4 lc rgb "green"    lw 2.0 
set style line 5 lt 5 lc rgb "black"    lw 2.0 

##############################


f(x)=a+b*x
fit [120:225] f(x) 'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat' via a,b

plot    'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat' using 1:2 with lines linestyle 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}", f(x) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black'
```

Here I plot the fitting graph from 1 to 120 as shown [image: here]. Also I want to plot the same graph from range 120 to 225 as in the picture [image: here].

Now I want a single plot which contain the two black lines and the red line.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the script you already have, you can use two functions to fit in the different ranges separately, and then use a conditional plot that selects one if x < 120 and the other one if x > 120:

```
f1(x)=a1+b1*x
fit [0:120] f1(x) 'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat' via a1,b1

f2(x)=a2+b2*x
fit [120:225] f2(x) 'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat' via a2,b2

f(x) = x < 120 ? f1(x) : f2(x)

plot    'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat' using 1:2 with lines linestyle 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}", f(x) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black'
```

Now, the way I would go about this, would be to generate a special fitting function, whose parameters would give me the point at which the slope changes as a result of the fitting itself. Say you call that point `x0` (for which the value of the function is `y0`), the slope at the left of it is `m1` and the slope at the right `m2`. Then the function at the left has the form `m1*(x-x0)+y0` and the function at the right has the form `m2*(x-x0)+y0`. The overall function can be defined in gnuplot as:

```
f(x) = x < x0 ? m1*(x-x0)+y0 : m2*(x-x0)+y0
```

and you can `fit f(x) "data" via x0, m1, m2, y0`. You can also generate this function without the condition using a step function:

```
f(x) = m1*(x-x0)*(sgn(x0-x)+1)/2 + m2*(x-x0)*(sgn(x-x0)+1)/2 + y0
```

After you fit, for which you might need to provide some initial values, you can `print x0` and you'll get the best value (that should be close to 120 in your case, as you know) for the position of the change in slope.

Comment: To get an idea of how powerful this can be, check this video I made for a gnuplot script fitting complicated functions to numerical data in real time (actually there is a 5-second pause for each graph for human readability): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7e1-6TC56s

Comment: Thanks for the help. Meanwhile, as for make the plot more readable, I would like to extent the lines at the intercept a little (like X) at x=120). I tried to change the range something like 1-130 and 110-225. But I did not get the CROSS at the 120. Could help?

Comment: In that case you cannot combine f1 and f2 into a single function f but you must do a `plot 'diff-xy-maltoLyo12per.dat', (x < 130 ? f1(x) : 1/0) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black', (x > 110 ? f2(x) : 1/0) lw 3.0 lc rgb 'black'`.

Comment: @Vijay To get the cross at 120 you need to fit to two functions that have the same value at x0=120: f1(x0) = f2(x0). The easiest way to do this is by fitting to f1(x)=m1*(x-120)+y0 and f2(x)=m2*(x-120)+y0 via m1,y0 for the first and *only* via m2 for the second. Or, even better, to the function(s) I proposed in the second part of my answer, which will actually give you the crossing point at the optimum position x0. Then you can plot it as Christoph explains above, but changing 130 -> x0 + 10 and 110 -> x0 - 10.